# How to use scipy minimize in a 2d array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to use the minimization function from scipy scipy.optimize.minimize.
I have a function `def f(x,a,b,c)` whose arguments are three scalars. I have 3 numpy matrices `A` `B` `C` and i want to calculate a matrix whose `(i,j)` component is the minimum of `f(x,A[i,j],B[i,j],C[i,j])` over all posible `x`. Using just `scipy.optimize.minimize(f,1,args=(A,B,C))` do not work. Any idea of how can I do it efficiently?

Comment: I cannot think of a better way than to define `g(x)=f(x,Aij,Bij,Cij)` and minimize it for each `i` and `j` in a nested loop.

Comment: I've tried this, but it is slow and maybe I can save computing time finding a way not using nested loops

Comment: Instead of trying to minimize each `g(x)=f(x,Aij,Bij,Cij)` you might want to define combined objective function:  `f = \sum_i \sum_j (g_ij)^2` and minimize that. That way you avoid for loops to run each individual optimization problem. You can also probably compute `f`  without for loops. The cost, of course, is solving a higher dimensional optimization problem. It just might be worthwhile.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that my matrices are big, 800×1000. Then I would need to solve a 800000 dimentional minimization problem, which I do not see feasible in a reasonable time. I think it is easier to solve 800000 one dimentional problem.